# How to add a button to another class

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a class called Restaurant, that has an FXML file, in that class, I have a button that when pressed opens another window called tables, that also has an FXML file, I have a minimize button in tables window.

What I want is when I press the minimize button in table, a new button will be added to the Restaurant window.

But I'm getting a null exception.
Can someone help me solve this.

This is the code for my minimize button:

```
@FXML
public void minimiza(ActionEvent event) {
     Button Tables = new Button("Mesas");
    try {
        Stage mesa = (Stage) ((Button) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        mesa.setIconified(true);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        RestauranteController controle = loader.getController();
        controle.adicionaBotao(Tables);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not working " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to just listen to the `iconified` property of the `Stage` from the `Restaurant` class. If the *minimized state* does not match the `iconified` state, you could create this property in the controller for the `tables` window yourself.

```
private int windowCount;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Button btn = new Button("Show new Window");
    VBox buttonContainer = new VBox(btn);

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        // create new window
        windowCount++;
        Label label = new Label("Window No " + windowCount);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Scene scene = new Scene(label);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        // button for restoring from main scene
        Button restoreButton = new Button("Restore Window " + windowCount);

        // restore window on button click
        restoreButton.setOnAction(evt -> {
            stage.setIconified(false);
        });

        // we rely on the minimize button of the stage here

        // listen to the iconified state to add/remove button form main window
        stage.iconifiedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                buttonContainer.getChildren().add(restoreButton);
            } else {
                buttonContainer.getChildren().remove(restoreButton);
            }
        });
        stage.show();
    });


    Scene scene = new Scene(buttonContainer, 200, 200);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

BTW: Note that without loading a fxml, `FXMLLoader` will never create a controller instance, let alone without the fxml being specified. Furthermore under no circumstances would it return the same controller instance as the one used with your `Restaurant` window.